# Rails 3.1: Problem saving record with not-null boolean mysql column (false saves as NULL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Using Rails 3.1rc5 and devise 1.4.2.  I have the following column on the users table

```
add_column :users, :has_dummy_password, :boolean, :default => false, :null => false
```

Without the `:null => false` clause if I do the following with an existing user record...

```
user.has_dummy_password = false
user.save
```

... then then in mysql the column has a value of NULL.

With the `:null => false` clause I (not surprisingly) get the following mysql error:

```
Column 'has_dummy_password' cannot be null
```

I can get around this by doing

```
user.has_dummy_password = 0
user.save
```

because "under the hood" booleans are implemented as tinyint in mysql.  That seems a bit unfortunate though.

Is it possible to actually set boolean column values with true/false in Rails 3.1 instead of 1/0?

Comment: MySQL's `BOOL`/`BOOLEAN` columns are `tinyint(1)`, although I thought using a `:default = false` would do the conversion.

Comment: Same problem here with rails 4 and last version of mysql2. Did you solve it ?