# How to set boolean value before save to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a `Item` model, which has a boolean `onshelf`.

I want to explicitly set `onshelf` value to `true` by doing something like `self.onshelf = true`. But I learn in the book **Agile Web Development** that, different database stores boolean value quite differently, and I'm afraid my practice might break my app in the future.

So I want to know, if I set boolean like `self.onshelf = true`, will Rails performs type-conversion (correctly)?

I know that `toggle!` method can do this too, but I don't like it to immediately save the result. I want to set every attribute first, then let `after_save` decides.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord (with its database drivers) will store boolean's in a way most appropriate for the particular database you're using.

Comment: Thanks! But [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150069/rails-3-1-problem-saving-record-with-not-null-boolean-mysql-column-false-saves) gives me some concerns. It seems ActiveRecord interprets `false` as `null`.

Comment: That's interesting; perhaps it's a bug in the driver.  It's definitely unexpected.  If you have access to the DB migrations you can probably set the column to 'not null default [whatever is false for the database].  That's actually what I normally do myself.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord should convert the ruby boolean to the closest thing in the corresponding DB.

Comment: Is it possible that `false` is converted to `null` instead of `0`? (say some DB regards `0` as `false`) [this guy reports such kind of issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150069/rails-3-1-problem-saving-record-with-not-null-boolean-mysql-column-false-saves)